# Error compiling very simple C program

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I decided I am going to teach myself "C" and saw a very simple "sample" program on a tutorial website, that I figured I would build off of it while I learn. The code is below

```
/* hello.c*/
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[1]);
{
  if (argc > 1)
    printf("greetings %s.\n", argv[1]);
  else
    printf("Please tell me your name.\n");
  return 0;
}
```

I am trying to compile with the following command

```
gcc -Wall -o hello_program hello.c
```

I am receiving the following error whenever I attempt to compile.

"hello.c:5: error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token"

I have been doing some googling and have not come up with a solid answer. I am 100% new to C (Linux/Bash/Unix is my world) and programming languages in general. The error message leads me to believe that the compiler fails at line 5, and that it wants '(' before the '{', I just cannot seem to get the right order. Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: Get rid of the semicolon after main().

Comment: Thank you very much. I can already see this being a rough month or two while I get all the basics and fundamentals down.

Comment: Also get rid of the 1 in your declaration of `argv`.  You can use `char *argv[]` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[1]);
```

should be

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
```

(without the semi-colon).

Also consider using braces in the `if` statement.

Comment: Why would OP need the braces?

Comment: @SergeyA - It is just good programming style and also removes the problem when somebody adds to the if statement and forgets to add the braces. Most coding styles I have worked with have made them mandatory

Comment: So my "if" statement should read?

     if {argc > 1}

Comment: I find it a **bad** programming style. What is even more important, I find a bad habit to enforce your personal preferences.

Comment: @SergeyA - ESA has this standard along with others. Coding standards help to prevent programming errors now and in the future. Also try to make the code consistent between developers.

Comment: @bluerojo `if (...) { ....} else {...}`

Comment: The `argv` declaration should be `char *argv[]`.

Comment: @TomKarzes - Thanks - I thought I removed it.

Comment: @EdHeal, 'don't sweat over small stuff'. This is one of the perfect example of small stuff.

Comment: @SergeyA - Coding standards lead to less error prone code.

Comment: @EdHeal, there are standards which do this. There are also standards that simply express personal preference of their authors, with no justifiable benefit. The braces thing (as well as where to put them - same line or next line) is one of those.

Comment: How can it be a standard if it is up to the whim of the author?

Comment: @TomKarzes in an ideal world it'd be `char * argv[static argc]`, but interestingly I don't know if that's technically legal for `main`...

Comment: @SergeyA - If you are interested here is the link http://www.esa.int/TEC/Software_engineering_and_standardisation/TECRFBUXBQE_0.html

Answer (score 3):

Been a very long time since I used C, but I beleive it should be this:

```
/* hello.c*/
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[1])
{
  if (argc > 1){
    printf("greetings %s.\n", argv[1]);
}
  else{
    printf("Please tell me your name.\n");
}
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `argv` declaration should be `char *argv[]`.

Comment: My mistake...I apologize.  It's been 20 years since I wrote anything in C.

Comment: While `int main (int argc, char *argv[1])` can be misleading, it's not wrong and is perfectly valid. The type of `argv` is `char**`. So `int main (int argc, char *argv[1])`, `int main (int argc, char *argv[])`, `int main (int argc, char **argv)`, `int main (int argc, char *argv[79])`, etc are all equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Basically in 'C' each statement, or declaration/definition is terminated with semicolon (unless it is some special one). On the global space (not in a function) you can only declare/define (declaration states that something with some type exists and name it while the definition also states it's content).

The line

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[1]);
```

Simply declares a function and not define it (the code you've written on the next line is not counted but it's interpreted as the next declaration/definition - which is not).

So in your case the semicolon must be after the function definition. Something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[1])
{
  if (argc > 1)
    printf("greetings %s.\n", argv[1]);
  else
    printf("Please tell me your name.\n");
  return 0;
};
```

Although if you look at the standard you'll see that the last semicolon is not needed. This is because 'C' have a special tolerance toward function types. As you see the function 'main' is not defined by using equal sign ('=') (as most other types) but instead directly using code in brackets ('{' [code] '}').

Another thing important to know is that all array/function types are treated differently in functions. In case of a parameter with such type, it's silently 'adjusted' to "pointer to"/"pointer to function returning". And in case of return value - compiler error (such thing is not allowed). Which means your 'main' function type will actually be:

```
int (int, char **)
```

And I suggest you don't fool your code readers and actually write the function type as it's actually is.

I don't claim my description is 1:1 with the standard or anything - I just explain the things as I see them.

*For some reason even putting the last semicolon is not a problem. I guess that is possible because in 'C' you can also have those empty statements (where like you only have the terminating semicolon).*

Comment: Thank you for the description and background information.